# Rails 3 Action Mailer Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form

I'm setting up a simple feedback form which just needs to send email and not save to the database.

I'm following this example
http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html

If I got to localhost:3000/supports/new I have no problems.

Now this all works except that I need this feedback form on the site homepage. If I use the same form I get the following error.

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Here's my form code.

```
<% form_for @support, :url => {:controller => "supports", :action => "create"}, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
<%= f.label "Name" %>:<br />
<%= f.text_field :name %><br />
<%= f.label "Phone" %>:<br />
<%= f.text_field :phone %><br />
<%= f.label "Message" %><br />
<%= f.text_area :message, {:cols => 27, :rows => 6} %><br />
<%= f.submit "Submit", :value => "Send Feedback" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I include this form in my homepage without causing the no method error?

Comment: Are you setting the @support variable inside your home controller action?

Comment: What if you remove `:html => {:method => :post}` cause it's set by default

Comment: @JCorcuera No I wasn't which resolves the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@JCorcuera No I wasn't setting the @support variable inside your home controller action which resolves the issue. Thanks for your help.